# Help with a proof using energy method for PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The question is

> Prove the uniqueness of solution of the initial value problem for $\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
> \Delta u - {u_{tt}} - q(x)u = f(x,t)\\
> u(x,0) = g(x)\\
> {u_t}(x,0) = h(x)
> \end{array} \right.$
>   where $(x,t) \in {\Bbb{R}^n} \times (0, + \infty )$ and $q(x) \ge 0$. Appropriate regularity can be assumed for $g(x),q(x),h(x),f(x,t)$.

I once solved this question but today when I looked at my solution again, I got a problem. The following is a scan of my solution. Zoom it in you can see it clearly.

The problem is where I circled. I defined the energy $E(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{{R^{n + 1}}} {w_t^2(x,t) + |{\nabla _x}w(x,t){|^2} + q{w^2}(x,t)dx} $.

In order to prove the claim, I need to show $E(t)=E(0)=0$. I have proved $E(t)=E(0)$, **what I have problem is** when $t=0$, why $|{\nabla _x}w(x,0){|^2}$, the middle term in $E(t)$, is equal to $0$?

[image]

Comment: Isn't this just because $\forall x \in \Omega,\ w(x,0) = 0$? So $\nabla_x w(x,0) = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $w(\cdot,0)$ is identically zero so it's gradient is also identically zero.